# JSP doesn't display texts from DB in a language other than English

Tags: java, jsp, character-encoding

I have the following code in my JSP

```
  ... <%
    out.println(request.getAttribute("textFromDB")); %> ...
```

When the JSP is called it just prints question marks (????..) instead of the actual text stored in a MySQL database which is not in English. What can I do to make it display the text correctly. I tried to change the charset and pageEncoding to UTF-8 but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't encoding nice? Unfortunately it's hard to tell where it gets wrong: Your database might store in another character set than UTF-8. Or your database driver might be configured to work in another encoding. Or your server defaults to another one. Or your HTTP connection assumes different encoding and your charset change comes too late.

You'll have to go through all those layers - and keep in mind that everything might look fine and it's been the long-past write-operations to your database that already messed up the data beyond repair.

Comment: when I write System.out.println(...) it prints the text as I want, but in browser No. Where should I look for the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(this.request.getHeader("Content-Encoding")); //check the content type 

String data = new String(this.request.getParameter("data").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8"); //this way it is encoded to byte and then to a string
```

---

if the above method didnt work you might wanna check with the `database` 
if it encode `characters to "UTF-8"`

or

you can configure URIEncoding="UTF-8" in your tomcat setup and just `(request.getAttribute("textFromDB"));` do the rest.

Comment: this.request... gives error request.getHeader(..) returns null.

Comment: well the get header returns the MIME type of the body of the request, or null if the type is not known.